# Electrical system probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is electrical system on the picture and $1,2,3$ and $4$ are switches.The probability of any of them to be closed is $0.5$. Find the probability that electricity goes from $A$ to $B$ and find the probability that electricity goes from $A$ to $B$ if $2$ is close.

[image]

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure how to aprouch the problem.. I know how to calculate probabilities, I think i have to do it with conditional probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want P(electricity is conducted | 2 is closed). Let $E_i$ denote the event that switch $i$ is closed. Electricity is conducted if $(E_1 \cap E_2 ) \cup (E_3 \cap E_4)$. You want $$P(\text{electricity is conducted} | E_2) = P[ (E_1 \cap E_2 ) \cup (E_3 \cap E_4) | E_2 ] = \frac{P[ ((E_1 \cap E_2 ) \cup (E_3 \cap E_4)) \cap E_2] }{P[E_2]}$$ by the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{  P(B)}$.

Now, simplify $$((E_1 \cap E_2 ) \cup (E_3 \cap E_4)) \cap E_2 = (E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 )$$ and note $$P[(E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 )] = P(E_1 \cap E_2) + P(E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4) - P[ (E_1 \cap E_2) \cap (E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 ) ]$$ and $$(E_1 \cap E_2) \cap (E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 )  = E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4$$.

Thus, $$P[((E_1 \cap E_2 ) \cup (E_3 \cap E_4)) \cap E_2 ]  = P(E_1 \cap E_2) + P(E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4) - P[ E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 ]$$ and by independence, $$P(E_1 \cap E_2) = P(E_1) P(E_2)$$, $$P(E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4) = P(E_2) P(E_3) P(E_4)$$ and similarly, $$P[ E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4 ] = P(E_1) P(E_2) P(E_3) P(E_4) $$.

Substituting back, we see $$P(\text{electricity is conducted} | E_2) = \frac{ P(E_1) P(E_2) + P(E_2) P(E_3) P(E_4) - P(E_1) P(E_2) P(E_3) P(E_4)} { P(E_2)}$$.

In this case, $P(E_i) = 1/2$ for all $i$, so just plug it in to get $2 ( 1/4 + 1/8 - 1/16) =\frac{5}{8}$ for the desired probability.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is the probability that [ ( 1 and 2 are closed) or (3 and 4 are closed) ]?

Comment: Well it should be 0.25 I think

Comment: @Diree The probability that [1 and 2 are closed] would be 0.25. So the probability in my hint would be higher.